# Electric billing system in dormitory

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have an Electric billing system. In one month every room in the dormitory have an amount of 1000 Philippine pesos for its electric bill ( *for sample)  that was consumed by the borders. So  its  divided by two border (for its sample) but it also depends on the day that the border enter the room.

What should I do so that the amount of electric bill is divided by number of borders depending on the day that they entered the room? My code for computing  was already based on the number of border in every room.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUjtP.png)  [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyjSx.png)

```
//compute of kilowatts 
                    double a, b;
                    a = Convert.ToDouble(txtpresent.Text);
                    b = Convert.ToDouble(txtlastmonth.Text);
                    b = a - b;

                    if (b <= 0)
                    {
                        b = 0;
                        MessageBox.Show("this bill is greather that to provious bill. \n     \n please! Check the Bill");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        txtperklwt.Text = "9.00";
                        txtconsume.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(b).ToString("###,##0.00");
                        Consume();
                        CountRMBORDERNO();
                        //txtperhead.Focus();

                        txtpresent.Enabled = true;
                        button5.Enabled = true;
                        btnSub.Enabled = true;
                        btnSub.Text = "Submit";
                    }
       //consume of number of border in a one month kilowatts
        private void Consume()
        {
            double x, y;
            x = Convert.ToDouble(txtconsume.Text);
            y = Convert.ToDouble(txtperklwt.Text);
            y = y * x;
            lbBillofMonth.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(y).ToString("###,##0.00");
    }
```

Comment: I just want to clear something up. You want to know how do you calculate how much a border should be charged for electricity used dependant on the time stayed in the room?

Comment: its depend the amount of monthly electricity bill that consumed by number of border in a room? i just wanna to know what should i do to know how to calculate the bill amount that based on the day that border enter into the room?

Answer (score 0):

First, Try not to mix Doubles and Decimals. Rather use Decimals everywhere. The reason is that Doubles are floating point values, and although they can store greater numbers, the numbers might differ sometimes. [Double vs Decimal](https://exceptionnotfound.net/decimal-vs-double-and-other-tips-about-number-types-in-net/)

So change the top part of your code do

```
double a, b;
a = Convert.ToDecimal(txtpresent.Text);
b = Convert.ToDecimal(txtlastmonth.Text);
b = a - b;
```

or for better looking code and error checking you can use, this is (C# 6+ code)

```
if(decimal.TryParse(txtpresent.Text, out decimal a) && decimal.TryParse(txtlastmonth.Text, out decimal b)
{
    //The rest of your code
}
```

Now you want to adjust the value for each border depending on when they entered the room. You obviously need to know when the border entered the room, and how many days is in the month. So here is a piece of code that you can use that will calculate there bill.

```
public Dictionary<int, decimal> CalculateBorderTotals(int monthNo, decimal totalConsumed, Dictionary<int, int> borderEnterRoom, Dictionary<int, int> borderLeftRoom)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();
    var minDay = borderEnterRoom.Values.Min();
    var maxDay = borderLeftRoom.Values.Max();
    var consumptionPerDay = totalConsumed / (maxDay - minDay);
    foreach (var item in borderEnterRoom)
    {
        if (borderLeftRoom.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            result.Add(item.Key, consumptionPerDay * (borderLeftRoom.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == item.Key).Value - item.Value) + 1); //The + 1 is discression depending how you calculate your number of days
        else
            result.Add(item.Key, consumptionPerDay * (DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, monthNo) - item.Value + 1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

All you have to do to call this is to pass the borderNumber and the day they entered/left the room into dictionaries, and it will calculate what each border needs to pay. For Example

```
var borderEntered = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var borderLeft = new Dictionary<int, int>();
borderEntered.Add(1, 3);
borderEntered.Add(2, 7);
borderEntered.Add(3, 1);
borderLeft.Add(3, 15);

var result = CalculateBorderTotals(1, 1000, borderEntered, borderLeft);
```

The result will show the bordernumber as well as the amount due.
Because you use all of the same kind of numbers, you can also use a different way of make it strings.

```
txtconsume.Text = b.ToString("###,##0.00");
```

and change your consume method and pass the numbers in there instead of getting it from the textboxes. Its better practise

```
private decimal CalculateConsumed(decimal costPerUnit, decimal TotalUnits)
{
    return costPerUnit * TotalUnits;
}
```

and use it like this

```
lbBillofMonth.Text = CalculateConsumed.ToString("###,##0.00");
```

Let me know if you understand.